# Make Selenium Hub use the first available node instead of round-robin?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have 1 Selenium Hub and 2 Chrome nodes running on ports 5900 and 5901, respectively.

When I run automated tests, it dispatches the request to the node running at 5900. When the test finishes and I want to run it again, it dispatches to the node at port 5901. This means I have to keep two VNC viewers running, one for each node.

I would like Selenium Hub to always use 5900 if it's "free".

These are the images and configurations that I'm using on docker-compose.yml:

```yml
hub:
  image: selenium/hub:3
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:3
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  depends_on:
    - hub
  environment:
    - HUB_HOST=hub
    - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
  ports:
    - ${DOCKER_GATEWAY_IP}:5900-5901:5900
  extra_hosts:
    - "${HOST_SINGLE_TESTS} ${HOST_MULTI_TESTS}:${DOCKER_GATEWAY_IP}"
```

*PS: I run two nodes because sometimes I run the tests in parallel.*

Comment: The answer seems to be somewhere around here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/grid/distributor "Responsible for being the central place where the Nodes on which Sessions run are determined."

Comment: Here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/grid/distributor/selector/HostSelector.java#L44-L64